# Apache 2.4 not reachable in windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, php5, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache 2.4 32bit with php 5 and sqlsrv library in windows server 2012.
Sometimes this stops to receive connection and browsers waits for answer for long time. The only way to unlock it is to restart the apache service.
I really don't understand what causes this trobule, it happends few times per week or many per days.
I tryed to update all apache/php components but I still get this error.
What can I do? How to set an high apache log level? Are there any known bugs about win server 2012 and apache?

Answer (score 0):

How many connections to your server are allowed? What is the limit of concurrent users allowed to connect to Apache?

Comment: I left the default configuration about inbound connections